# Mostrar dados do banco de dados na pagina

Tags: php, html

Eu estou com problemas para mostrar os dados do banco na página.

Mensagens de erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```php
    <?php
$host = "localhost";

$db   = "faa";

$user = "root";

$pass = "";

// conecta ao banco de dados

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or 
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar

mysql_select_db($db, $con);

// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados

$query = sprintf("SELECT  id, nome, preco, descricao, download FROM projetos");

// executa a query

$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());

// transforma os dados em um array

$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);

// calcula quantos dados retornaram

$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);

?>
```

Comment: Essa função, assim como outras funções em seu código foram depreciadas use [mysqli_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.select-db.php), [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php), [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) e [mysqli_num_rows](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Answer (score 1):

Bom, de acordo com o erro retornado ele nos diz que a função que você tentou chamar NÃO EXISTE ou NÃO ESTÁ DEFINIDA.

De fato a partir do PHP 5 as chamadas das funções MySQL não são mais escritas como *"mysql..."*, eles acrescentaram um *"i"* à todas as chamadas de funções deste gênero, altere o **mysql_select_db** para **mysqli_select_db**

Além disso, se você não for alternar entre outras DB's no seu código é mais interessante definir a DB utilizada direto na inicialização da conexão:

```
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
```